# Comparing values within a row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

I have a table in Excel with a large amount of rows containing data from before and after a certain procedure. I want to compare the values in each row, so that:

- I see the values that stayed before and after the procedure
- I see the values removed during the procedure (aka the values that were there before)
- I see the values added during the procedure (aka the values that weren't there before)

So, in the end, I would have a table like this:

```
Before                  After                   Common          Removed         Added
Max     Marie   Peter   Eve     Peter   Marie   Marie, Peter    Max             Eve
Paul    Sarah   Marie   Sarah   Marie   Max     Sarah, Marie    Paul            Max
Peter   Lucas   Marie   Sarah   Lucas   Chris   Lucas           Peter, Marie    Sarah, Chris
```

What is the most effective way to achieve this?
Is there a good function for this, or should a macro be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy if you are prepared to deal with `Common`/`Removed`/`Added` as blocks of the same size each as `Before` and `After`:

[image: SO33519183 example]

In G2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$D2:$F2,0)),"",A2)
```

In J2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$D2:$F2,0)),A2,"")
```

In M2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$A2:$C2,0)),D2,"")
```

With each copied two cells to the right and then all copied down to suit.

Comment: I shall try and use this method, although my "blocks" will be 20 cells wide, so I will have to merge them later to make the table more readable. If anyone knows an easier method, please share, but this will do for now. Thank you!